# can not see the lamp source

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

After installed Apache2, MySQL, PHP, phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 13.10. I would like to see the installing folder and files, but I can not see them, it seems that Ubuntu does not allow user to access the source files even I use sudo cd or sudo ls.

I would like to learn that it is possible to see the files using sudo command.

Your help and information is great appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible to see the files which are related to a particular package.

```
dpkg -L <pacakge-name>
```

From `dpkg --help`,

```
-L|--listfiles <package> ...     List files `owned' by package(s).
```

Example:

```
dpkg -L apache2
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the information and help, Regards, Inung